# Optimize DELETE query where rows contain large data (files serialized in Base64)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are many useful tips about optimizing DELETE queries when there are a huge number of rows to delete. However, in my case, it's not too many (~3-4000 rows), but each row contains fields with files serialized in Base64. Most of them are above 10 MBs, but there are a few more than 100 MBs. The DELETE query takes more than 1 hour to complete. Is there a trick I can use to make it significantly quicker?

I've tried batching, but that actually made it worse for some reason (more hours worse).

I've disabled all the constraints temporarily (`ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all` on each table), it helped ~10-20 minutes, but it's still painfully slow.

My query looks like this:

```
    DECLARE @OrphanedIds TABLE (DocumentId int);
    INSERT INTO @OrphanedIds
        SELECT DocumentId
        FROM Table2
        WHERE ContentType = 'Something';

    DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE DocumentId IN (SELECT DocumentId FROM @OrphanedIds);
    DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Id IN (SELECT DocumentId FROM @OrphanedIds);
```

Note that Table2 contains a foreign key to Table1 (`Table2.DocumentId = Table1.Id`), but I've disabled the constraints temporarily as mentioned above.

Comment: Where is your database log file stored - on fast or slow storage? Such kind of deletion uses quite a lot of log space; if this is slow, then procees may wait for IO. Just an idea, not answer.

Comment: What do the session wait stats for the long-running operation show? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 You can always try creating a new table, loading that with the rows _not_ deleted, then drop/rename.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the document id a primary key in the table:

```
DECLARE @OrphanedIds TABLE (DocumentId int PRIMARY TABLE);
```

Then use `EXISTS` (or `JOIN`) rather than `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM Table2
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @OrphanedIds o WHERE table2.DocumentId = o.DocumentId);

DELETE FROM Table1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @OrphanedIds o WHERE table1.DocumentId = o.DocumentId);
```

You might find that cascading delete foreign keys can then keep the data in synch -- if you want to ensure that in the future.